# Looking for a way to check all possible combinations of four dice in python

Tags: python, list, loops, combinations

I have a single list (or iterable, I'm quite new to Python so I don't know what the difference is) that contains four integer elements, each element ranging from 1 to 6, including 6. My program is essentially a dice game that checks for a lot of different conditions and I'm not entirely sure if all of them work correctly.

I want to check for every possible combination of dice in order to debug the program.

Example: first loop `[1, 1, 1, 1]` -> second loop `[1, 1, 1, 2]` ---> seventh loop `[1, 1, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

- You already have the list of values

  ```
  values = [list(range(1, 7)) for _ in range(4)]
  res = product(*values) # * to flatten and pass the 4 dices as separate parameters
  print(list(res))
  ```
- Directly pass one `dice` values, and specify that you have `4` dices

  ```
  res = product(range(1, 7), repeat=4)
  print(list(res))
  ```

Both will give you

```
[(1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 1, 4), (1, 1, 1, 5), (1, 1, 1, 6), 
 (1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 2, 2), ...  
 (6, 6, 6, 1), (6, 6, 6, 2), (6, 6, 6, 3), (6, 6, 6, 4), (6, 6, 6, 5), (6, 6, 6, 6)]
```

Comment: Quick reply! Code is still not complete (I have to figure out how to get each combination into my dice list) but this got me on the right track, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product
for l in product(range(1,7), repeat=4):
   # do something with l, for example print(l)
```

Comment: Please add a short explanation.